# Why do some host volumes in Docker containers give the error "too many levels of symbolic links"?

Tags: nfs, symbolic-link, docker, autofs

I'm running docker with a host directory mounted:

```
$ docker run -v /usr/groups/thing -ti imagename /bin/bash
```

Files in `/usr/groups/thing/foo` are accessible:

```
# ls /usr/groups/thing/foo
a b c
```

But files in `/usr/groups/thing/bar` are not:

```
# ls /usr/groups/thing/bar
ls: cannot open directory /usr/groups/thing/bar: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

This is on Debian, and `/usr/groups/thing` is an automounted NFS volume.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by directories not being automounted when the container is run. I had thought that `/usr/groups/thing` was the automount point, but evidently the sub-directories are auto-mounted individually. The solution is to make sure each one is mounted *before* entering the container:

```
$ (cd /usr/groups/thing/foo; cd /usr/groups/thing/bar)
$ docker run -v /usr/groups/thing -ti imagename /bin/bash
# ls /usr/groups/thing/bar
d e f
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to this problem, and while the solution I found certainly won't be for everybody, it was a subtle part of my setup that was causing the issue.

To save space, I'd moved the Docker directory from my `%APPDATA%` directory on my SSD, to my much larger HDD, and setup a junction to point to it in its new home.

I eventually remembered that this was the case, and moved the directory back. Restarted my PC, and the error stopped occurring.

Like I say, that's pretty niche, but it solved it for me.

Comment: and then you eventually remember that you did this for a reason, mainly cause you had no space on the system drive....

Comment: This answer doesn't apply well to the NFS-issue of the original poster.

Comment: @ppuschmann - It could do, as all I meant to say was, that if there's an extra symbolic link / hard link / junction / whatever, that you might of forgotten about, it could cause this issue. Not sure why I was marked down for given a possible solution...